# scalacheck Properties set

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Using [scalacheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck), one can define some [Properties](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Properties.scala#L29) as such:

```
object MyProps extends Properties("MyProps") {
  property("myProp1") = forAll { (n:Int, m:Int) =>
    n+m == m+n
  }
  property("myProp2") = forAll { ... }
  property("myProp3") = forAll { ... }
}
```

I would like to override the default minimum number of successful tests ([minSuccessfulTests](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/43fa83bf516e5bf68990830331ada9cfad3c445d/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Test.scala#L23)) for just one single property, for example just for `"myProp2"`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PropFromFun` you can try implicitly converting to your own `Prop` implementation:

```
class PropWithParameters(prop: Prop, params: Test.Parameters) extends Prop {
    def apply(prms: Gen.Parameters) = prop(prms)

    def check(): Unit = {
         // Call super.check with params.
    }

    def withParams(moreParams: Test.Parameters): PropWithParameters = {
        // return a new instance with params merged with moreParams.
    }
}

object PropWithParameters {
    implicit def convert(input: Prop): PropWithParameters = {
        // Initialize with empty params here.

        // I'm not sure if implicits get aligned easily 
        // in case of a subclass.
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
object MyProps extends Properties("MyProps") {
    property("myProp1") = forAll { (n:Int, m:Int) =>
        n+m == m+n
    }
    property("myProp2") = forAll { ... } withParams(customParams)
    property("myProp3") = forAll { ... }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that override the default min number of successful tests for *each* property in my original example? I only want to override it for one property.

Comment: It sure would. I started writing a different answer but then changed it to this, thinking this was simpler.

Comment: This would be simpler. The problem is, I have one test that fails nondeterministically only 1 out of 1000 times. So I want to up the number of times that particular test is run, without slowing down the test suite by running all the other tests more than necessary. I *could* just move this one nondeterministic test into another test suite, but I wanted to see if I didn't have to. In the end, this problem may be a limitation of using `Properties` in this way...

Comment: Perhaps. Still, take a look at the code now. I didn't test it or anything but the idea is there.

Comment: So I coded up your suggestion, and it's looking close, but the override for `def check` isn't being hit, and so we still don't have control over the default min successful tests. Looking at the source, [Properties](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/82cf61dc903de8c1de9b0dfc0aae5ea8cc67231b/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Properties.scala#L47), is itself a `Prop` and so overrides `def check`. And I think that this `check` method will be called only once for *all* sub-properties, meaning that the individual `Test.Parameters` we set elsewhere for each `property("...")` have no effect.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/43fa83bf516e5bf68990830331ada9cfad3c445d/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Test.scala#L301) is where we ultimately get the `minSuccessfulTests` value. This comes from the `prms` passed in [down here](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/43fa83bf516e5bf68990830331ada9cfad3c445d/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Test.scala#L399).

Comment: Btw this is easy to do with specs2 but that adds a new dependency to your build.